# InterServer Communication through Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I have Chat Client Server Application, which we are scaling up. so I need to do interserver communication between two chat servers.

> Problem is: Suppose there are two servers A and B. now Suppose client
>   C1 is TCP Connected with Server A and Client c2 is TCP connected with
>   Server B.
>           Then problem is: as a same appication client C1 and c2 should be able to identifty each other as logged in and available online, but
>   that is not happening becase       there is no inter server
>   communication.
>
> Possible solution no 1 is : Log in server A and Server B into each
>   other using TCP connection. Here i can forward the login XML
>   message(String) and DataInputStream to      other server through the
>   TCP connection. so every login is transfered to the other server so
>   that every client is accessible to each server and Client C1 can see
>   Client C2 as logged in(online) and vice versa.
>
> Problem with Solution 1 is: Suppose now client C1 can see Client C2 as
>   available online and Client C1 sends message to Client C2. what will
>   happen is Server A Will try to write to DatainputStream for the client
>   C2 which is established on Server B and not on Server A. here is the
>   problem the code will break here and Server A will not be able to send
>   messages to Client C2.

Any inputs will be appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to scale to multiple machines? How many users are we talking about? Are you using non-blocking IO already or still one-thread-per-connection? If at all possible, avoid scaling out over multiple machines -- it's a (stateful) world of pain.

Comment: thanks for reply.Well my client want to make sure that if he will get more hit to his product he should be able to SCALE UP. We discussed about benchmarking and all but its new product and he is unable to calculate possible hits.. So i have to implement interserver communication anyhow as i explained above. the product is already being implemented its using Thread per connection.am thinking about non blocking sockets, its coming soon.so any possible solution in your mind for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look on how the IRC servers implements such kind of functionality. I believe that you just need to write another server which will handle your servers as the clients and request to them in order to find the concrete user.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2810

Comment: Thanks for re3ply @AlexTheo. Can you suggest helpful links for your answer?

Comment: I see that actually the IRC server implements the ( servers server ) internally so you need to implement the server for your servers internally if you need to follow the irc's way.
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2810

Comment: Otherwise just implement another server (servers server) (separately) which in my opinion is more flexible solution.